# MySQL CHAR Foreign key results in 1215 error

Tags: mysql

I have the following table setup:

```
CREATE TABLE USER (
  id                  CHAR(36)     NOT NULL,
  user_id             VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
  password            VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
  email               VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
  enabled_ind         INTEGER(1)   NOT NULL,
  other_user_oid INTEGER(19),
  other_user_pod VARCHAR(10),
  last_changed_date   TIMESTAMP    NOT NULL,
  last_changed_by     VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  created_date        TIMESTAMP    NOT NULL,
  created_by          VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  UNIQUE KEY ix_user_id (user_id),
  UNIQUE KEY ix_user_email (email),
  UNIQUE KEY ix_user_pod (other_user_oid, other_user_pod)
)
  ENGINE = InnoDB
  CHARACTER SET = utf8
  COLLATE = utf8_bin;

CREATE TABLE ROLE (
  id                CHAR(36)     NOT NULL,
  name              VARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL,
  last_changed_date TIMESTAMP    NOT NULL,
  last_changed_by   VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  created_date      TIMESTAMP    NOT NULL,
  created_by        VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  UNIQUE KEY ix_role_name(name)
)
  ENGINE = InnoDB
  CHARACTER SET = utf8
  COLLATE = utf8_bin;

CREATE TABLE USER_ROLES (
  user_id           CHAR(36)     NOT NULL,
  role_id           CHAR(36)     NOT NULL,
  last_changed_date TIMESTAMP    NOT NULL,
  last_changed_by   VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  created_date      TIMESTAMP    NOT NULL,
  created_by        VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  INDEX (user_id),
  INDEX (role_id),

  FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
  REFERENCES user (id)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,

  FOREIGN KEY (role_id)
  REFERENCES role (id)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
  ENGINE = InnoDB
  CHARACTER SET = utf8
  COLLATE = utf8_bin;
```

When I go to create the USER_ROLES table, I get a "Cannot add foreign key constraint" error. Most of the similar issues I've found on stackoverflow and while googling around seem to have to do with the charset and collation, but from what I can tell, I'm doing that correctly, so I'm not really sure what the issue is here. I've been trying a bunch of different things for a while now, but nothing seems to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It works for me on [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/89bf11).

I did need to change the email in users to 200 characters rather than 500.  That should be sufficient.  The longer length was too long for the index, so the table was not being created.

Also, you are storing the password as a string.  You should be sure that you are only using encrypted passwords.

Comment: Strange...I wonder why it doesn't work for me. Maybe it's a version issue. I am hashing all passwords using BCrypt.